# jquery datatable row click with responsive

Tags: datatables, responsive

i'm using jquery datatable with responsive
the (+) responsive sign show correct when screen size decrease
i had event row click on the table

```
 $('#datatables tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {//Code});
```

My problem that the responsive button fires both function
the responsive (Default) function that expand the row
and my row click event

is there a way to Prevent that

Edit : Same happens with any attached button on the row if the button is clicked it execute both button click event and row click event

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem with UGLY workaround
first i added empty td index 0 so that the responsive button show on it
second i changed the event from tr click to td click
then check for the td index

```
$('#datatables tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
                    var tdIndex = this.cellIndex;
                    if (tdIndex == 0)
                    {//For Responsive Click leave Empty
                    }

                    else { //Normal Code}
```

i still waiting a better solution

Comment: After looking for hours, this is the best results I manage to deal with the same situation. It is annoying how the onclick row overlaps the responsiveness +/- icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html

if that does not help please assign a class to the column like:

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "MyColumn", "className": "toggle-btn-add" }
]
```

and call it like:

```
$('#datatables tbody').on('click', 'td.toggle-btn-add', function (e) {//Code});
```

Hope this helps